# Rails Observer Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot access a has_many relationship in an observer before_destroy method.

For example, say I have a User and a User has many posts:

```
 class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    def before_destroy(user)
        Rails.logger.info "user has #{user.posts.size} posts"
    end
end
```

The user.posts array will be empty.

Please advise on how to gain access to a models relationships.

Thank you.

Comment: did you check if the posts get deleted before the observer get's fired? is there a cascade delete or somthing?

Comment: I see what you're saying. There's a dependent destroy on the posts. Is there a way to order the dependent destroy to fire after the before_destroy on User?

Comment: Yeah, the problem was with dependent: :destroy. In the end had to remove the dependent and have some clean up code.